# How to access input elements from a React function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I currently have a form that is auto generated based on the amount of "Activities" a current user has. Each activity has a name and a value. My goal is to submit these values to the backend to update them. Yet I can't figure out how to reference these inputs. I was trying to read about using "ref"s, yet they come back with {current:null}

[image: auto generated list (excuse the placeholder text)]

Here is the auto generated list (excuse the placeholder text)

When I inspect console here is what I find from the ref:

[image]

Here is my code:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useStore } from "react-redux";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as actions from "../store/actions/patientSide";

export function ActivityTemplates() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const store = useStore();
  const ref = React.createRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    // Update the document title using the browser API
    dispatch(actions.getTodaysActivityTemplates());
  }, []);
  
  const activities = store.getState().patientSide.todays_activities;

  const listedStuff = activities.map((activity) => (
    <div>
      {activity.activity_name}
      <label for="value"> Value: </label>
      <input
        type="number"
        id="value"
        defaultValue={activity.value}
        min="0"
        max="10"
      ></input>
    </div>
  ));
  
  const saveActivities = () => {
    var inputs = ref;

    console.log(inputs);
    // Insert code to run the call to the backend
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1> Activity Templates</h1>
      <form id="form" onSubmit={saveActivities()} ref={ref}>
        {listedStuff}
        <input type="submit" name="save" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ActivityTemplates;
```

I am very new to React and JS and honestly have very little idea of what I'm doing, but if someone could point me in the right direction that would be awesome!

**EDIT**: After sleeping on it, I've realized I've just been trying to force react into my HTML. I believe I should instead use a React Form Hook, and do it properly from the ground up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <form onSubmit={handleOnSubmit}>
        <label>User Name</label>
        <input type="text"  name="username" /><br/>
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password"  name="password" /><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>



 const handleOnSubmit = (event) => {
    const formData = new FormData(event.target);
    const formDetails = {};

    event.preventDefault();
    for (let entry of formData.entries()) {
      formDetails[entry[0]] = entry[1];
    };
    console.log("formDetails", formDetails);
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, this is the route I ended up taking. I pretty much deleted everything and rewrote it using a handleSubmit function. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the value

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState();
```

Then give your input a `onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}`

I would change the id though

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to redo the whole thing with React Form Hooks, and use the OnChange methods. That seems to be the proper way.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the input fields value from "FormData" on onSubmit.

```
const saveActivities = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(event.target);

   // Insert code to run the call to the backend
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined". I think it's because it's trying to read it before it actually has data. After looking into it more, I realize I was just trying to shove React into HTML... Seems the proper way is to use React Form Hooks or something, so I think that'll be the way I'm gonna go.

Comment: @StevenTeglman. Please check my new answer.